# SQL Replication issue with Primary key

Tags: replication

I have a table which is to be replicated using Transactional Replication.
This table has a composite primary key . These are a combination of varchar and numeric columns.
I want to understand if this table can be replicated with a composite primary key?

Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this table can be replicated with a composite primary key.  Just keep in mind with Transactional Replication there must be a declared primary key for the published table.

[Considerations for Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151254.aspx)